# how to replace [^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]+ to "" in a file by sed or anything?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

I find and replace some strange characters in xml file with text editor.
with regular expression

```
[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]+ ---> ""
```

Now, I need to it in linux command line.

I ask you how to use sed or anything that same find and replacement job in linux command line.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the substitution string ?

Comment: I want to find character like [^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]+  replace to "" (empty string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
sed 's/\\u\(0009\|000A\|000D\|0020\|D7FF\|E000\|FFFD\|10000\|10FFF\)//g' <<< "[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]"
```

Before replacing, be sure you really want to replace this characters as some of them are tabs, newlines, spaces...

**Update :**

One more generic pattern based on your 4-5 hexa codes sample :

```
sed 's/\\u[0-9A-F]\{4\}[0-9A-F]\?//g' <<< "[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]"
```

will replace all `\u` followed by 4 or 5 hexa codes

Please note that a capitalized word (ie Foo) following a 4 hexa code string will match :

`\u0000Foo` will be changed to `oo` as the `F` of Foo will match the 5th optional hexa code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried like this sed -n 's/\\u(0009\|000A\|000D\|0020\|D7FF\|E000\|FFFD\|10000\|10FFF)//g' xml_27_2.xml > test2.xml and then test2.xml still contains characters.

Comment: The pattern used just match the characters from your sample code. Do you want to replace all unicode escape sequences ?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all unicode escape sequences in files

Comment: Mr. Kenavoz, I appreciatae your solution, thank you.